# Chinese equivalent of "no worries"

Tags: word-requests

"No worries" in English is used as a statement expressing that the speaker regards a task / problem / setback as inconsequential, or that a task is easy to complete. For example:

> A: "You're going to be late for work."
>
> B: "No worries. My boss doesn't get in 'till lunchtime."

or

> A: "Can you have this completed by Wednesday?"
>
> B: "No worries."

Is there an equivalent phrase in Chinese?

Comment: I also use "no worries" to accept apologies in informal situations, for what it's worth. (E.g., "Sorry to put all of this on you." "No worries.")

Comment: First situation: 没事儿; second situation: 没问题 (no problem). In Jon's example, it would be 没事儿 as well.

Answer (score 6):

Although not a direct translation, "沒關係/没关系" or  "沒問題/没问题" can also sometimes mean "don't worry" depending on context.

> 沒關係/没关系 - It doesn't matter (note: not suitable for the 2nd example)
>
> 沒問題/没问题 - No problems (ok for both examples)

Answer (score 5):

Another equivalent expression is 不要紧.

Answer (score 4):

For the first meaning of regarding something as inconsequential, I think 没事 could also work since it can mean "it won't be a problem".

你會遲到了！

沒事， 我的老闆中午才會到辦公室。

Or something like that. I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

I would say in both cases, "别担心".

> 别 : *don't*
>
> 担心 *to worry*

so "别担心" is very close to "don't worry" or "no worries".

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. "No worries" doesn't mean the same thing as "don't worry" -- in the OP's second example, for instance, it really just means "yes." There's no implication that anyone is actually worried, or even that they might be.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest translation is 放心吧. It literally translates to "put your suspended heart down" and its contextual meaning is "no worries".